# How to experience make content center in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Note: Please read the description it is little different with other topics: 
I have a `container` div in my template in that container i have six div so i want to show them center align using this following way.

- On desktop version three columns(center of `container`)
- On iPad version two columns(center of `container`)
- On mobile version one column(center of `container`)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box_container">
            <img src="../product_img_10.png">
            <a href="#" class="product_title">TITLE FOR HIM</a>
        </div>
    <div class="box_container">
     <img src="../product_img_10.png">
        <a href="#" class="product_title">BOXES FOR HER</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box_container">
     <img src="../product_img_10.png">
        <a href="#" class="product_title">BOXES FOR COUPLES</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am interested to know is there any class that solve this problem or need to edit some `LESS`files code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use CSS media queries to achieve this quite simply : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i am thinking about bootstrap will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question (maybe add a mock-up image?), however what about the following?

```css
/* I'm not sure what you're stylings are, but just taking a stab */
.box_container { text-align: center; }
.box_container img { display: block; }
.box_container img, .box_container p { margin: auto; }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="box_container">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="" />
                <a href="#" class="product_title">TITLE FOR HIM</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="box_container">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="" />
                <a href="#" class="product_title">BOXES FOR HER</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="box_container">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/50" alt="" />
                <a href="#" class="product_title">BOXES FOR COUPLES</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the above:

- XS Screens (<768px) [Phones]
  The three pieces appear in one single column.
- SM Screens (≥768px) [Tablets]
  The three pieces appear in two columns (with third carrying onto next line).
- MD Screens (≥992px) [Desktop]
  The three pieces appear in three columns.

Comment: Its working but still when my browser get the resulation of `767px` its not showing in center align please let me know what i should do next?

Comment: @Srackoveryflow_guy: Maybe I just don't understand what you're after, but I see them centered in one column at `767px`.

Comment: how it can be, i want help?